# How to combine useState and useEffect properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to compare 2 inputs value. The typical password/repeat password input in a form.

Using onChange react useState render the DOM but not immediately because I shopuld use useEffect.

But I'm not sure how to combine both. I'm conscious there is other answers replying something similar but I can't apply to this case.

**This is my useSstate**:

```
 const [user, setUser] = useState({
        username: '',
        password: '',
    });
```

**This is my onInputChange function**:

```
const onInputChange = (e) => {
        if ((e.target.id === 'password') === (e.target.id === 'confirmPassword')) {
            console.log('Match!')
        } else {
            console.log('DO NOT Match')
        }
        setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
        console.log('User Updating values: ', user)
    }
```

**This is the input (MUI textfield)**:

```
    <TextField
      id="password"
      name="password"
      label="Password"
      type="password"
      onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
    />
                                                
<TextField
      id="confirmPassword"
      name="confirmPassword"
      label="Confirm password"
      type="password"
      onChange={(e) => onInputChange(e)}
 />
```

Could you help me with this, please?

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find how it works

[CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-brown-pukfw8?file=/src/App.js)

This is not best practice because you should match password on submit or on blur event trigger on each input.

Ask me if you need furthur help !

Thank You.